# Regression or classification with two dependend variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, dependent-variable

I have a dataset with many variables about images and two dependent variables: one is a number that a person gives to that image and the other is which group that person belong (we have to groups, say A and B).

My job is: given the data of one new person, with the values of the image variables and the number that the person gives, predict if she/he belongs to group A or B.

I was thinking to create two models of regression to predict the numbers, one for group A and other for group B, and applying the new data in both see what was close to the real numbers answered.

Does that make sense? Is a better method, maybe to classification, that match with this task?

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you have one dependent variable: the person's group. And it sounds like classification is the way to go. As a start, you could use a logistic regression with the target of Group A or Group B. If your model is good, the resulting value (on the response scale) can roughly be a percentage chance of being in the one class.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the english, not that good. My doubt is that the number that people aswered is related to the variable of the images, so is dependent of those variables. Can I use these two kind of information ( the number and image variables) together in the feature vector for classification? This is not a problem of correlation or something?

Comment: @Jess: Not knowing all the details, my guess would be that the rating the person gives _is_ correlated to the image features. Otherwise, either the rating makes little sense or your image features don't describe it very well. You're correct that you need to think about highly-correlated variables in any regression/classification, but I don't think there's a special issue in this case. It'd be something to watch for, though.